# Is adding 'readonly' to a DirectInjection service (in Symfony) useful?

Tags: php, symfony, immutability

In Symfony you can inject **services** into the controller and use them. I get the suggestion that the properties can be readonly. Please see the follow two examples:

```php
class ExampleAController
{
    public function __construct(
        private FooService $fooService,
        private BarService $barService,
    ){}
}

class ExampleBController
{
    public function __construct(
        private readonly FooService $fooService,
        private readonly BarService $barService,
    ){}
}
```

Are there any realworld advantages/disadvantages to adding `readonly` here?

Adding readonly ensures it doesnt change and helps protect the code from unwanted changes, but in the case if a **service**, which often has its own dependencies, rewriting the property will be *a lot* or work and will not go unnoticed in any way.

To be clear, **I'm specifically talking about services**. If, for example, you inject a `private readonly string $apiKey` I can see somewhat of a benefit.

Comment: *"but I have yet to encounter someone who actually changes an injected service"* — The point is, if you were to _accidentally_ write `$this->FooService = 'bar'` somewhere, PHP would catch that error for you. That's what the `readonly` annotation does.

Comment: No, that is caught because you try to write a `string` to a variable of type `FooService`. You could do `$this->fooService = new FooService()` somewhere, but that is an expection in my example.

Comment: @deceze So I request to reopen my question. I'll also try to clearify this in my answer

Comment: Whatever. It protects against you accidentally changing the property when it shouldn't be changed. That's what it does. It also serves as a tiny bit more documentation as to the purpose of the property. Use it or don't. If you think the advantages are too slim for Symfony services in particular, then don't.

Comment: I was kinda hoping for a better answer than "Whatever, Use it or dont" :') IMO its a more specific question than the generic readonly. Yes I think the advantages are too slim so I dont apply them, but without feedback no improvement, I might be very wrong, there might be a good reason I didnt thinkg of to add it.

Comment: It does come down to personal opinion and preference. What you have is objectively a read-only property, so it would make complete sense to annotate it as `readonly`, because that's what it is. That should really be the end of the story. If you say `readonly` adds too much clutter and that realistically there's little chance anyone would accidentally change that property anyway… well… that's your opinion and preference then. PHP doesn't care one way or the other, technically it works either way.